# Force URL to open in running instance of IE

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

the same question is asked couple of times before. but I've little issue which is not addressed before.
I'm trying to open url in new Internet explorer tab while my chrome and ie both browsers are running.The code is below

```
public static void openNewInternetExplorerTab(ref InternetExplorer ie, string url) 
 {
  // Open the URL in a new tab of the given InternetExplorer instance
  ie.Navigate2(url, BrowserNavConstants.navOpenInNewTab, ref m, ref m, ref m);
  // Make InternetExplorer visible
  ie.Visible = true;
 }
```

this code always open new tab in chrome browser instead of IE. How I can open in Internet Explorer.